# How to use FirebaseAuth error codes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the `AuthErrorCode` in Firebase but I keep getting errors. Here is my code:

```
private func handleErrors(err: NSError, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: err.code) {

        switch errCode {

        case .errorCodeWrongPassword:  //Enum case 'errorCodeWrongPassword' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WRONG_PASSWORD)
            break

        case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:  //Enum case 'errorCodeInvalidEmail' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.INVALID_EMAIL)
            break

        case .errorCodeUserNotFound:  //Enum case 'errorCodeUserNotFound' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.USER_NOT_FOUND)
            break

        case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:  //Enum case 'errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE)
            break

        case .errorCodeWeakPassword:  //Enum case 'errorCodeWeakPassword' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WEAK_PASSWORD)
            break

        default:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.PROBLEM_CONNECTING)
            break

        }

    }

}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? If you didn't see the errors in my code here they are:

```
Enum case 'errorCodeWrongPassword' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'

Enum case 'errorCodeInvalidEmail' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'

Enum case 'errorCodeUserNotFound' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'

Enum case 'errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'

Enum case 'errorCodeWeakPassword' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode'
```

Let me know if you guys have any ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are imported in Swift as `AuthErrorCode.weakPassword` for example: remove `errorCode` from all the case values.

```
private func handleErrors(err: NSError, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    guard let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: err.code)
        else { return }

        switch errCode {

        case .wrongPassword:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WRONG_PASSWORD) // Transform to wrongPassword
        case .invalidEmail:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.INVALID_EMAIL)
        case .userNotFound:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.USER_NOT_FOUND)
        case .emailAlreadyInUse:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE)
        case .weakPassword:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WEAK_PASSWORD)
        default:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.PROBLEM_CONNECTING)
        }
  
}
```

Swift suggestions:

- Don't use `break` in switch statements, they break by default after the case is done (`fallthrough` allows you to check each case after a match)
- Switch `NSError` for `Error` (Firebase uses NSError, if you want to switch to Error read [Swift 4 get error code from error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747048/swift-4-get-error-code-from-error/50747101))
- Is LoginErrorCode your custom class ? Consider switching to Swift >= 3 syntax for the cases (lower camel case)

Comment: "Switch NSError for Error" - Default Error class has no code variable.

Comment: Firebase still uses NSError so you should use NSError. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747048/swift-4-get-error-code-from-error/50747101

Comment: Yea i know that, but you have mentioned to use Error class instead of NSError which is used in FirebaseAuth

Comment: Answer already updated with possible workaround