# Swift 4 get error code from error

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable that is defined like as an Error and this is what it looks like when I print it:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-2 "Canceled by user." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Canceled by user.})
```

What I am trying to do is get that Code of -2...how would I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can unwrap the optional `error` first and compare the `-2` case.

```
if let error = error {
   switch error._code {
      case LAError.userCancel.rawValue: // or -2 if you want
        // do something
      default:
        break
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I wrote this small extension:

```
extension Error {
    var errorCode:Int? {
        return (self as NSError).code
    }
}
```

Using:

```
if error.errorCode == -2 {
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to cast your Error to LAError (Local Authentication error) and switch its code property:

```
if let error = error as? LAError {
    switch error.code {
    case .userCancel:
        print("userCancel")
    default:
        print("unknown error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want use the `code` property on `NSError`:

```
var e = NSError(domain: "Pizza", code: 31, userInfo: nil)
e.code  // 31
```

Answer (score -2):

You can cast the Error to an NSError object -- in Swift, Errors can be "toll-free bridged" to NSError objects with no conversion necessary.

NSError objects contain a `code` property (as Int):

`let errorCode: Int = (error as NSError).code`